# Excel: Replace 0 which is returned by UNIQUE() by another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, unique

In Excel I use the unique() function to get unique values of a column. As soon as I have empty rows in my column, they appear as "0".

Formula for D2: `=UNIQUE(C2:C8)`

[image: Current situation]

**My question:**

How can I replace the "0" with another value e.g. "Empty cell"?

The result should look like this:
[image: Desired result]

I know that I can use `UNIQUE()` with `FILTER()` to ignore empty values / cells. However, in my case I want to keep them just "name" them differently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need filter()?

[image]

Just set the last argument to 1 in unique()

Or you can do this with if() as well:

[image]

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify more what I would like to achieve. My goal is to *keep* the empty cells, just rename the 0 to something else.

Comment: @vigri The second image shows the 0 to now be renamed "EE" - really what else do you want?

Comment: The second picture is the solution - thank you! When I wrote my comment, only the first image was there.