# Returning unique values from a table with names & dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a mother table with cumulative data of customers names & their date of purchasing. The purchased customers varies from month to another, some repeat purchasing in the same month & others don't. I want to create a table of 2 columns to return the names of customers purchased each month. As an example of the mother table:

```
column1   column2
Harry      01-06-2022
Harry      22-06-2022
Harry      30-06-2022
Michel     30-06-2022
Paul       05-07-2023
Harry      07-07-2023 
Michel     12-08-2023
```

The recommended table should be like this:

```
column1   column2
Harry      06-2022
Michel     06-2022
Harry      07-2023
Paul       07-2023
Michel     08-2023
```

I failed to create a suitable formula

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: Replace 0 which is returned by UNIQUE() by another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77089484/excel-replace-0-which-is-returned-by-unique-by-another-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try-

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A8,TEXT(B2:B8,"mm-yyyy")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this formula:

```
= UNIQUE(MAP(A2:B8,LAMBDA(d,IF(COLUMN(d)=2,TEXT(EOMONTH(d,-1)+1,"MMM-YYYY"),d))))
```

`MAP` turns each date into the first of that month - like that `UNIQUE` can return the result you want.

Comment: I think avoiding `IF()` here will be good choice. Upvote from me.

Answer (score 1):

Another one if date 01-06-2023 is recognized as text ant not as an actual date

```
=UNIQUE(HSTACK(A1:A7,RIGHT(B1:B7,7)))
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: `RIGHT()` function will fail if they are true date.

Comment: @Harun24hr I know! As other solutions will fail if it is text and not true date. I have specified in first line that this solution is in case of given data being text and not actual date